# Code Snippet stopped working

Tags: python, normals

I've been using this code to clear custom normals for a large quantity of objects and its stopped working. I don't understand code very well and don't know what to change to make 3.4 understand the command.

This is the code snippet I run through the text editor:

```
import bpy

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

for o in selection:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = o
    bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()
```

Comment: If it helps, I'm getting a Traceback Error - "Lots of text" - Conext is Incorrect.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I guess there is a non mesh object selected like Camera, Light, Empty. Insert `if o.type == 'MESH':` at first line in your loop.

Comment: Ah yup, there it is. I had a curve hiding in there that had been exported with the meshes I needed to clean up. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)